# Discovering best ulimit settings

Tags: docker

I am trying to configure Docker Deamon to follow CIS bencmarks. One of the recommendations is to configure default ulimit parameters when starting. They give the example of 
`dockerd --default-ulimit nproc=1024:2048 --default-ulimit nofile=100:200`

How do I know how to calculate the best settings for `nproc` and `nofile` for my particular environment?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, to set those, you would need to know what your application upper limits might be. You would need to first run the applications and put them under the type of loads you expect them to be under and then measure the limits and open files.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230346/how-to-check-ulimit-usage for information on how to check the limits. You would need to get the limits for all the PIDs that you are running as containers. I would then pad them a bit to account for headroom.

Even then, you are likely to go down a path of chasing limits constantly as it will probably be difficult to accurately get all of them correct before the application goes to production.